# programming logic problem

Tags: math, combinations

I need a function that can give me all possible combinations of a array back.

Example:

```
$source = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$target = thisiswhatisearch($source);
```

Now the `$target` should look like:

```
array('a','b','c','ab','ac','cb','abc')
```

I dont need the `aa`, `bb`, `cc`.

I also dont need the the `ba`, `ca`, `acb`.. because the order isn't important to me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations

Comment: I found this as a part of the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861966/php-clean-up-permutated-array

Comment: On the bottom of that page is a solution which uses a pear package. I´ll take that one (-: - thanks for the wikipedia link - Permutation was a good word to search for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to be language agnostic but i guess its C like:

```
function combinations(array arr)
{
  combos = array();
  for (int i=1; i<2**arr.size(); i++)
  {
    int x = i;
    int c = 0;
    str = "";
    while(x>0)
      {
        int rem = x % 2;
        if(rem == 1)
          str += arr[c];
        x = x / 2;
        c++;
      }
    combos.add(str);

   }
return combos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia entry for [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) has a [link to C code](http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/generating-combinations-1/) that does this.

Answer (score 0):

That's an out of the mind solution. It is probably not the fastest and cleanest one, but it kind of works. It's in Java, because I had it open:

```
public class Combination {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] source = {"a","b","c"};
    List<String> result = combineMe(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(source)));
    for (String string : result) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public static List<String> combineMe(List<String> source) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (source.size()==0) {
        result.add("");
        return result;
    }else{
        String tmp = source.remove(0);
        source = combineMe(source);
        for (String string : source) {
            result.add(("" + string).trim());
            result.add(tmp + string);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

The first entry in the resulting list is a fake one, and needs to be removed at the end